# Using core/session is logging user out

Tags: login, ajax, session, user

I'm adding products to the cart using an ajax call. Inside the ajax responder I have the initial code.

```
Mage::app();    
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ['name' => 'frontend']);
```

If a user is not logged in it adds the products to the cart with no problems, but if a user is logged in, the second line causes the user to log out. Leaving the store in a logged out state with the last product added to the cart. Do I need to do anything to preserve the users session?

Comment: Is this code outside of the scope of Magento application ?

Comment: Yes, it's a single php file acting as an ajax responder. That's why I'm initializing the Magento application to access events, sessions etc. I was using Mage::init() first, but that didn't give me access to events.

Comment: Take a look at the method `preDispatch` inside `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class. That is how Magento initializes the sessions. You might need to do the same somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the described behavior can happen if there's sessions from unstable code. After clearing the browser cache it works perfectly.